# SSRS report url edit for two folders

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have created 2 report folders in SSRS configuration services. I want to show different url for both the folders, as they are published from same server. Can you please let me know how to do it?

Comment: So what urls are now and what are expected urls?

Comment: Current 2 folders are **Folder A** http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFolder+A&ViewMode=List                                                                   and **Folder B** http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFolder+B&ViewMode=List... So I want urls like http://localhost/_Reports_A_/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFolder+A&ViewMode=List  http://localhost/_Reports_B_/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFolder+B&ViewMode=List

Comment: Current 2 folders are **Folder A** http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFolder+A&ViewMode=List                                                                   and **Folder B** http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFolder+B&ViewMode=List...                                                 So I want urls like (only virtual directory should change)                                  http://localhost/Reports_A/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFolder+A&ViewMode=List  http://localhost/Reports_B/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFolder+B&ViewMode=List

Comment: After analysing I have found solution installing new instance for another folder as it has different data source.